# Angular 5 custom validation display exception

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on learning Angular 5 reactive forms and have tried to make an example custom validator that displays an error message on the form. When I try to type anything in the project name field (called "namey" here), I get this exception (the line number given is just pointing to the start of the input in the HTML):

```
AppComponent.html:20 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cannotBeTestx' of null
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:27)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14338)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13507)
at callViewAction (core.js:13857)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13789)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13513)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14739)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14276)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11299)
at eval (core.js:5783)
```

Here is the component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.projectForm = new FormGroup({
    namey: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.cannotBeTest1]),
    email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    status: new FormControl('1')
  });
}
```

Here is the custom validator code:

```
cannotBeTest1(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
  const name: string = control.value;
  if (name && name.toLowerCase() === 'test') {
    return {'cannotBeTestx': true};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML for this element (there are a couple of other form elements that are working fine and after that is a closing form tag):

```
<form class="ui form-vertical" [formGroup]="projectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="project-name">project Name</label>
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="text"
        id="project-name"
        placeholder="Enter project name"
        formControlName="namey"
      />
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="projectForm.get('namey').errors['cannotBeTestx'] && (projectForm.get('namey').touched || formSubmitted)">-->
        please enter a valid project name
      </span>
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!projectForm.get('namey').valid && (projectForm.get('namey').touched || formSubmitted)">
        please enter a project name
      </span>
    </div>
```

I have been messing with things, renaming stuff and come down to this part of the error display being the issue:

```
projectForm.get('namey').errors['cannotBeTestx']
```

Interestingly, if I remove that error message display in the HTML, the custom validator works correctly (I can't make the project name "test") and I get the other, generic error message display. So it seems to be something about the way I am checking to see if that custom validator is invalid but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<span class="help-block" *ngIf="projectForm.controls['namey'].hasError['cannotBeTestx'] && (projectForm.controls['namey'].touched || formSubmitted)">

<span class="help-block" *ngIf="!projectForm.controls['namey'].valid && (projectForm.controls['namey'].touched || formSubmitted)">
```